# Fast streaming of JSON data over HTTP in ASP.NET & IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, iis

I have a MVC action which streams JSON data over HTTP to clients, the data can be as large of 400,000 to 600,000 records.

I am facing a performance issue when it comes to streaming the data.
for example for 10,000 records I have managed to minimize the mapping to 1.3 seconds and JSON generation to 1.5 seconds.

However I facing a problem when it comes to streaming the data to the client, it takes about 7 seconds to stream the data to the client.
I am using IIS 8 and on the Action itself I have turned off the Session.

Tested the same with 40,000 records, it took about 8 seconds to query and generate JSON, but it takes as long as 25 seconds to stream the data.

My code (my custom ActionResult) somewhat look like as below:

```
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "application/json";
response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

response.Write("[ ");
int c=0;
foreach(var item in Data) {
  if (c>0) response.Write(", ");
  response.Write(ConvertToJson(item));
  c++;
  //here tried to flush in intervals too - only managed to save like 2 seconds
}
response.Write(" ]");
response.End();
```

The response is the HttpContext.Response and in the lines above this code, I am setting all the necessary headers as well.

Is there any way to optimize ASP.NET or IIS to stream the data faster?

**UPDATE**:

It seemed that when I used a production server with much better bandwidth the transfer time is significantly decreased. Another idea is to have the client request the data in chunks for better performance, the only way I can control that though is through introducing API limits....

Still looking for optimization ideas, insights as to what items to consider in order to better the performance.

Comment: You're going to be limited by network latency and routing for sure. Not much you can do there unless the response is gzipped, which takes a little extra server activity. Can you see if the data is being compressed coming back to the client? Also, check the full bandwidth of data being returned. Keep in mind if you're testing a production server that this isn't going to be the only request it is responding to and thus is only sharing part of the bandwidth.